# Lucene .Net newbie query issue

Tags: c#, lucene, lucene.net

First time using `Lucene` so I apologise in advance if some terminology is incorrect.

I am modifying a `Lucene` query and am not getting the results expected. A search term is used to build a boolean query, and I need to add an extra field to search. This field, called `tags` is already part of the index (confirmed with `Luke` for Lucene) but hasn't been included in the search.

Currently the boolean query looks like this:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(settings.SearchTerm))
  {
    booleanQuery.Add(KeywordQuery(settings.SearchTerm, analyzer), Occur.Must);
  }


 private Query KeywordQuery(string searchTerm, StandardAnalyzer analyzer)
   {
     var parser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(Version.LUCENE_29, new[] 
       { 
         LuceneMedia.IndexFields._Title, 
         LuceneMedia.IndexFields.Description
       }, analyzer);
     string sTerm = LuceneUtilities.AddSearchWildCard(searchTerm);
     Query query = LuceneUtilities.ParseQuery(sTerm, parser);

     return query;
   }
```

(`indexFields` are `constants` that refer to the field names)

I thought it would be a case of extending the array of tags like so:

```
 new[] 
            { 
                LuceneMedia.IndexFields._Title, 
                LuceneMedia.IndexFields.Description, 
                LuceneMedia.IndexFields.Tags 
            },
```

but this bought back no results when searching for a `tag` I know exists, but results for a `title` I know exists. so I thought maybe I should change `OCCURS.MUST` to `OCCURS.SHOULD` but a `tag` search brought back all results.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way to search multiple fields, unfortunately I hadn't re-indexed!